# Trouble with LINQ query and XML elements

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've run into an issue trying to work with xml files in visual studio and was hoping someone could point out my error for me. What I'm trying to do is read in all the child elements, then find the longest child  from the parent .

I've tried many, many variations of this code, For Loops, LINQ queries, etc and can't seem to make it work as expected. I get one of two errors, a null reference exception or this:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[VB$AnonymousType_1`3[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String,System.Int32],System.Int32]
```

Here's my code, I'm hoping someone can explain why this doesn't work with xml files when it works with virtually everything else I've done to this point. Thank you!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim States As XElement = XElement.Load("USStates.xml")
    Dim query = From na In States.Descendants("state")
                Let names = na.<name>.Value
                Let length = names.Length
                Order By length Descending
                Select length

    TextBox1.Text = query.ToString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem, I resolved my issues with the following code:

```
 Dim query = From st In States.Descendants("state")
                Let stateName = st.<name>.Value
                Let length = stateName.Length
                Order By length Descending
                Select stateName

    For Each item In query
        If item.Length > 10 Then
            output.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
```